# Why I can not use Prediction in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Why I can not use Prediction in Flutter?

I tried to use this methods, but I cannot use Prediction??

```
lacemark _pickPlaceMark = Placemark();
  Placemark get pickPlaceMark => _pickPlaceMark;
  List<Prediction> _pridictionList = [];

  Future<List<Prediction>> searchLocation(
      BuildContext context, String text) async {
    if (text != null && text.isNotEmpty) {
      http.Response response = await getLocationData(text);
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
      print("Location is :" + data["status"]);
      if (data["status"] == "OK") {
        _pridictionList = [];
      }
    }
  }
```

It's show me error `The name 'Prediction' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument. Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'Prediction'.`

Comment: can you post the full code, it's difficult to debug where the error is

Comment: Because the code cannot find the definition of `class Prediction() { ... }`. Also, the method `searchLocation()` does not return  `Future<List<Prediction>>` but `Future<void>`.

Comment: @Dabbel  Because I saw this tutorial `https://www.dbestech.com/tutorials/flutter-google-map-search-location-auto-complete-address`